# System.FormatException when Converting a Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am receving the error

> `System.FormatException`

when I click on `Button1` after entering a persons details

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{    
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("You have successfully added a Person!");    
        Person p = new Person(TextBox1.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text), 
        TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, Convert.ToBoolean(DropDownList1.SelectedValue), TextBox5.Text);    
        Label1.Text = (p.PresentPerson());
    }
}
```

Person class:

```
class Person
{
    public int Age { get { return Age; } set { Age = value; } }
    public string Name { get { return Name; } set { Name = value; } }
    public string DOB { get { return DOB; } set { DOB = value; } }
    public string TelNo { get { return TelNo; } set { TelNo = value; } }
    public bool Gender { get { return Gender; } set { Gender = value; } }
    public string Address { get { return Address; } set { Address = value; } }
    public string enterPerson;

    public Person(string name, int age, string dob, string telNo, bool gender, string address)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        DOB = dob;
        TelNo = telNo;
        Gender = gender;
        Address = address;
    }

    public string PresentPerson()
    {
        return enterPerson = "Name: " + Name + "\n" + "Age: " + Age + "\n" +  "Date of Birth: "
        + DOB + "\n" + "Telephone Number: " + TelNo + "\n" + "Gender: " + "\n" + "Address: "
        + Address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the entire exception message, including traceback.

Comment: You are blindly converting the value of TextBox2.Text to an integer and the SelectedValue of your DropDownList to a boolean. Clearly one or the other are not what the Convert.ToXXXX expects to be. If you take a bit of your time to learn how to use the debugger these errors will be solved in no time

Comment: Sorry yes:
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to check value of gender and then set the proper bool value:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("You have successfully added a Person!");
        bool gender = (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Male") ? true:false;
        Person p = new Person(TextBox1.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text), 
        TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, gender, TextBox5.Text);

        Label1.Text = (p.PresentPerson());
    }
}
```

This sets gender to true only if value is male.

A bit more advanced would be to use enums https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx:

```
class Person
{
...
enum Genders {Male, Female, NotSet};
public Genders Gender { get { return Gender; } set { Gender = value; } }
public Person(string name, int age, string dob, string telNo, Person.Genders gender, string address){...}
...
}
```

And maybe a switch statement like this where you can hande other casses easily:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("You have successfully added a Person!");
            Person.Genders gender = Person.Genders.NotSet;
            switch(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
            {
               case "Male": gender = Person.Genders.Male; break;
               case "Female": gender = Person.Genders.Female; break;
            }
            Person p = new Person(TextBox1.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text), 
            TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, gender, TextBox5.Text);

            Label1.Text = (p.PresentPerson());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if SelectedValue is null?

Comment: Then it would set gender to false. This is because this solution is "simple" and not for more complex cases.

Comment: Of course, but we don't know if this is what the OP wants. My comment was just a tip for you to add some clarification to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors use validator to your textbox such as regularexpression or custom. 
Eg: `\d+` for your age textbox.
This will help you minimise errors. As your representation of Male and female is boolean, then you could do something like:

```
bool gender = DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Male"
```

and pass it to constructor.